# How to do Google Play Games in Unity 5.5f?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have my plugin but when I type:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate ();
((PlayGamesPlatform)Social.Active).Authenticate ((bool success) => {}, true);
```

I have this problem:

> C:\Users\Espada\Desktop\Unity Workspace\Crashball\Assets\GooglePlayGames\ISocialPlatform\PlayGamesLocalUser.cs(18,18): Error CS0535: 'GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesLocalUser' no implementa el miembro de interfaz 'UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.ILocalUser.Authenticate(System.Action)' (CS0535) (Assembly-CSharp)
>
> C:\Users\Espada\Desktop\Unity Workspace\Crashball\Assets\GooglePlayGames\ISocialPlatform\PlayGamesPlatform.cs(18,18): Error CS0535: 'GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform' no implementa el miembro de interfaz 'UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.ISocialPlatform.Authenticate(UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms.ILocalUser, System.Action)' (CS0535) (Assembly-CSharp)

How can Activate my plugin? What plugin use ? I use: `GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.01-force-same-gms-version` it is correct?

I just find (I thinkg) the solution but I don't know how do it, how? What have I write in my Script?

https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/pull/1500/files

Answer (score 1):

> just find (I thinkg) the solution but I don't know how do it, how?
>   What have I write in my Script?

Click on the *View* icon on that [link](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/pull/1500/files) from GitHub. It will show you the whole `PlayGamesLocalUser.cs` file changes.

Copy that code, go to your *Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesLocalUser.cs* then replace replace whatever that is in the *PlayGamesLocalUser.cs* file with the code you just copied.

Here is the *View* icon I was talking about:

[image]

And [here](https://github.com/kiberzauras/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/670024bf6cb6c211a6214f57f76609aca13814ed/source/PluginDev/Assets/GooglePlayGames/ISocialPlatform/PlayGamesLocalUser.cs) is the link you will get when you click on it.

Comment: Yes, but when I do this, (copy his 2 Scripts), My program say me 33 errors, 33 references to **old folders** like, Google Basic API and this link only has 2 scripts....

Comment: I think I find the definitive solution : https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity and I download "current build" **GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.36** and now I can activate this plugin sice Unity, Is this plugin the correct solution ?

Comment: You have to scroll down too on that [link](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/pull/1500/files) too. There is another file called `PlayGamesPlatform.cs`. You click on it's View button and do the-same thing you did for `PlayGamesLocalUser`.

Comment: The solution was Google Play Games Plugin 0.9.36 and Google Play 10.0 , i  already gave you +1 thanks

Comment: Your question was **I just find (I thinkg) the solution but I don't know how do it, how? What have I write in my Script?**. I gave you answer to that by showing you how to get the complete modified scripts. Don't forget to accept [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if your problem is solved.